# It takes more time to upload the data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

I am using `xcode` 6.4 and `objective-c`.My app's functionality is given below.It fetch all members of a public event in the facebook.The app fetch member's name and images and send to a server.After sending the details to server,the app fetch the details from server(name and image) and display the details in TableView.Some public events has thousands of members.In this case it takes more time to upload the details to server and fetch the details from server.Is there any way to solve this problem.Please help me(I am new to iOS development)

Comment: You can try compressing the HTTP body, but that requires coordination with your server.  Ultimately, you can only shorten the time by sending less data.

Comment: What I can say that you want to Sync data from FB to server via Mobile app as middle player. Definitely it will take time. I would suggest you to please perform sync between FB & server (avoid App as middle player). If in case you are not able to do this then download an info/data from FB->Show in Device->Upload on server. Perform this process in Queue for better performance.